# What spices are used to make a mexican fajita seasoning?

Tags: seasoning, mexican-cuisine

I'm trying to make my own homemade fajitas, for both vegetarian and non vegetarian tasters.

I know they have grocery store pre-mixed fajita seasoning, but I'd like to know how to make my own.

Comment: I'm going to try this and post an account of my results. Thanks Chad, Ocaasi and Adam for giving me a good place to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Penzeys](http://www.penzeys.com/cgi-bin/penzeys/p-penzeysfajitaseas.html) (a spice co.) makes theirs from:

salt, black pepper, paprika, Turkish oregano, cayenne pepper, garlic, celery, Mexican oregano, basil, nutmeg, cumin, marjoram, thyme and rosemary.

No numbers are given, and you probably don't need two kinds of oregano, but I've made it before with a similar list, and it is generally insensitive to precise ratios. I'd start with

2x black pepper, paprika, oregano, cayenne, garlic,

1x basil, cumin, marjoram

1/2x nutmeg, thyme, rosemary

bulk up with salt (store-bought stuff is mostly salt), and experiment from there. You can probably find more on google. Add hotter things or anything you find interesting :)

Answer (score 4):

Salt, pepper, garlic powder, onion powder, cumin, coriander (seed), cayenne pepper, paprika (or smoked paprika).

Cayenne ups the heat, cumin ups the cumin, paprika ups the sweet/smoke.

That's what I'd put in mine.

Answer (score 4):

Mexican oregano is well worth seeking out; it tastes totally different than the typical European oreganos. Pretty easy to find if you have even a moderately well stocked Mexican grocery in your area.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess: salt, pepper, cayenne, cumin, sugar, onion and garlic powder

or you can try this which has a few more items in it: http://busycooks.about.com/od/homemademixes/r/fajitaseasonmix.htm

Comment: Sugar?  Interesting...